# calculating what second of the day an event occurred

Tags: php

I made some code that works, but it seems very inefficient.  I am charting circles on a canvas to show when events happen during a work day.  To do this I find the number of seconds of the day this happened, then convert this to minutes to show.

My question is why do I have to go `strtotime(date('...',strtotime(time)))` and call strtotime twice?

When I just had it like `strtotime(date('Y-m-d',time)` I would get a negative value.

```
<?php
$time_concerned = '2014-10-31 02:00:00';

$start_day_temp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($time_concerned)));
$end_day_temp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime($time_concerned)));
$num_seconds = $end_day_temp - $start_day_temp;
//divide by 60 to get minutes.  divide in half to make fit on 720 scale.
$num_conv_minutes = (($num_seconds/60)/2);

echo '  ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";';
echo '  ctx.beginPath();';
echo '  ctx.arc('.$num_conv_minutes.'+ x_inbound,y_truck_arrivals,5,0,2*Math.PI);';
echo '  ctx.fill();';
echo '  ctx.stroke();';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$time_concerned = '2014-10-31 02:00:00';
echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($time_concerned))); 
echo "\r\n"; 
echo strtotime($time_concerned);
```

Try this. [Fiddle](http://3v4l.org/VC93o).

These are *almost* the same thing. The only reason they're different is because when you convert the string to a date you're dropping the second minutes and hours, so PHP puts it to midnight and you lose the part that tells you you did all this at 2am.

This is useful the first time you use it because you need to get the timestamp of midnight to subtract from the other timestamp. However, the second time it's just redundant.

So here's how you do it..

```
$time_concerned = '2014-10-31 02:00:00';
$start_day_temp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($time_concerned)));
$end_day_temp = strtotime($time_concerned);
```

Comment: Thanks!  that cleans it up a little.  I guess no way around the double use of strtotime() to find the beginning of the day.

Comment: There are other ways you can do it, but this way is probably the quickest.